# How to make minmax_element to return the element with least index in case of a tie

Tags: c++, std, c++14, stl-algorithm

```
#include<utility>
#include<alogrithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
  int n=5;
  int s[]={3,5,1,5,5};
  auto r=minmax_element(s,s+n);
  cout<<r.second-s<<endl;
  cout<<*r.second;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the code to  print the maximum element in the array with its index.
I want to  the maximum element with the least index (the first max in case of a tie)

### How do i modify the above code to get the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need only the max element, why don't you use the `std::max_element()` function? It will do exactly what you want.

```
auto r = std::max_element(s, s+n);
cout << r-s << endl; // index of the maximum element in [s, s+n)
cout << *r  << endl; // value of the maximum element in [s, s+n)
```

Comment: Link to documentation for std::max_element(): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: I have tried that way like this int max=*max_element(s,s+n) , but then how would i get the index?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> v = {1, 4, 2, 2, 3};
auto r = minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
cout << r.first - v.begin() << " " << r.second - v.begin() << endl;
```